# Autocomplete does not show after setValue

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm building a form where I use the [Angular Material Autocomplete module](http://Angular%20Material). I load the options from a server and I filter them with an input. It works great, and now I wanted to add a "clear" icon to clear the field if needed.

The clear option clears the field, but it doesn't show the autocomplete options again. It shows them when I manually delete the input contents with backspace but not with the icon.

To "clear" the field I use this code:

```js
clear(control: string): void {
    this.form.get(control).setValue('');
}
```

And I call it from a `mat-icon` component:

```html
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput type="text" ... >
    <mat-icon matSuffix (click)="clear(fieldName)" ...>
        clear</mat-icon>
</mat-form-field>
<mat-autocomplete> ... </mat-autocomplete>
```

Where fieldName (string) is the name of the control I want to clear.

And this is how I filter the autocomplete options:

```js
this.filter = this.form.get(field).valueChanges.pipe(
    startWith(''), // Don't even know what this does...
    map(value => this.options.filter(option => option.name.toLowerCase().includes(value.toString().toLowerCase())))
);
```

I suspect that maybe there's an error with the `setValue('')` inside the `clear()` method. Or maybe its the filter method that I'm using.

Here's the full example in StackBlitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-autocomplete-clear9zzmw2

Comment: I see that the select still shows the options even after I use the clear button, but I need to remove focus on the select and then focus it again; you want to display the options immediately after clicking the clear button?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems like you want to open the options panel as soon as you click on clear button. This is not happening because once you select an option of `matAutocomplete`, it selects the value and close the options panel. In order to open it again you have to either *remove character from textbox* or *type matching character sequence*.

Over here you are manually clearing up the value, but it doesn't intimate `matAutoComplete` to open the panel. If you look at source code of `matAutocomplete` you will find that [`input`/`blur`/`keydown`](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/autocomplete/autocomplete-trigger.ts#L110-L113) event happened are responsible for opening and closing panel. You can do that by triggering those event manually(into separate change detection cycle). But the most convenient way would be calling `openPanel` method of `matAutocomplete`.

So lets concentrate on how can we do call [`openPanel`](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/api#MatAutocompleteTrigger) method of `matAutocomplete`. Since you've used `matAutocomplete` with combination of `matInput`, it does exported as [`matAutocompleteTrigger`](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/api#MatAutocompleteTrigger). So add `#automcomplete="matAutocompleteTrigger"` inside your matInput element like shown below.

**Markup**

```
<input
  matInput
  type="text"
  #automcomplete="matAutocompleteTrigger"
  placeholder="Select something"
  formControlName="autocomplete"
  [matAutocomplete]="autocompleteStuff"
  required>
```

Now using `ViewChild` decorator we can query `autocomplete` template variable

**Component**

```
// It will have an autocomplete component instance
@ViewChild('automcomplete') autocomplete;
//...
//...
clear(control: string): void {
    this.form.get(control).setValue('');
    // call autoComplete `openPanel` to show up options
    setTimeout(()=> {this.autocomplete.openPanel() })
}
```

[**Running Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-autocomplete-clear9zzmw2-kzg5lo?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

---

Alternative solution could be blur out and focus in to the input programmatically. For the same just keep `#automcomplete` on `matInput` and then query the element using `ViewChild` and then trigger event on the `nativeElement` of queried result.

**Html**

```
<input
  matInput
  type="text"
  #automcomplete
  placeholder="Select something"
  formControlName="autocomplete"
  [matAutocomplete]="autocompleteStuff"
  required>
```

**Component**

```
@ViewChild('automcomplete') autocomplete;
//...
//...
clear(control: string): void {
    this.form.get(control).setValue('');
    setTimeout(()=> {
      this.autocomplete.nativeElement.blur();
      this.autocomplete.nativeElement.focus();
    })
}
```

[**Forked Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-autocomplete-clear9zzmw2-iz2umo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: I was trying the `openPanel()` method but I didn't use `setTimeout()`... Thanks!!

Comment: @JCAguilera yupe, thats because it doesn't understand somehow in same change detection cycle. I was trying to find the answer why extra CD is needed here, but thereafter I didn't get time to dig more in :(

Comment: If I'd able spend more time on this, then will definitely share more insight on this :) Thanks :)

Comment: It's working fine thank you